# How to bind a DataGrid to a Design Structure Matrix (DSM)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I was wondering if someone could help me out in indicating how I could go about binding a WPF DataGrid to a Design Structure Matrix (DSM). As shown in Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnmK6.png), the DSM comprises Row-Header and Column-Header with the same entries in the same sequence. I would like to make the cells of the Table/Matrix/Grid clickable with two text boxes for inputting information about the intersection (Row and Column).

Here is what I have done.

The Cells Class:

```
public class Cell
{   
    public CellPosition Position { get; set; }        
    public Collection<Entry> Entries { get; set; }     
    public Collection<Rule> Rules { get; set; } 
}
```

And here is the main Window

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var irule = new Rule(1.ToString(), "Informal", "Some informal Rule", "All Chamfers are equal");
    var frule = new Rule(2.ToString(), "Formal", "Some formal Rule", "chamfer.equal(all)");
    var pos11 = new CellPosition(1.ToString(), 1.ToString());
    var pos21 = new CellPosition(2.ToString(), 1.ToString());
    var entry = new Entry("TableTop", "TableTop", "Test Case TableTop");
    var entry1 = new Entry("TableFoot1", "TableFoot1", "The Foot of the table");
    var entry2 = new Entry("TableFoot2", "TableFoot2", "Test Case TableFoot");
    var entries = new List<Entry>();
    entries.Add(entry);
    entries.Add(entry1);
    entries.Add(entry2);
    var dsm = new DSM(entries);
    foreach (var cell in dsm.Cells)
    {
        dsm.AddRuleToCell(cell, irule);
        dsm.AddRuleToCell(cell, frule);
    }

    var kafaSession = new Session();
    kafaSession.SaveModel(dsm, "C:\\OwnStuff\\TestFiles\\Results\\output.xml");

    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
    Console.ReadLine();


    KafaGrid.ItemsSource = dsm.Cells;
}
```

Output: [DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJgrU.png)

[Binding DataGrid to Design Structure Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnmK6.png)

I've also looked into DataTables, but I can't figure out how to define the Column-Head and Row-Head to be the same ...

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: My data source is a collection named Cells. The collection contains 
Position Position { get; set; }
Collection<Entry> Entries { get; set; } 
Collection<Rule> Rules { get; set; } 

I did a test with three entries in a dsm object as such  

MyGrid.ItemsSource = dsm.Cells;

The result is just the structure of the Cells Class

I would like to define the Column-Head and Row-Head and populate the cells with the values of my Collection